# Time Defference with Two Times in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, laravel-4

I have two time like below :

```
$c _time = 11:32 AM

$t_time = 03:48 PM
```

Now I want to find the Difference in the format of **00:00:00**

How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: JpDevs please up-vote the answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('11:32 AM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('03:48 PM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo "<pre/>";print_r($interval);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');

?>
```

Output:-

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 4
    [i] => 16
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
)
04:16:00
```

Comment: hi is that possible to accurate my question output

Comment: you can append 0 in hour and second and minute by checking if they are not two digits. you can do it i hope. just if else condition.

Comment: [Why not just format DateInterval?](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: @JishadP: have you even looked at DateInterval::format()? This code is just nonsense...

Comment: Sorry my mistake.Beg a parden. @Glavic and JishadP please check my edited code.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh: now your code is the same as mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple solution:

```php
$dt1 = new DateTime('11:32 AM');
$dt2 = new DateTime('03:48 PM');
echo $dt1->diff($dt2)->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/310039)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Laravel, you can use `Carbon` for some easy, easy diffs:

```
$c_time = "11:36 AM";
$t_time = "03:48 PM";

$c = Carbon::createFromFormat("H:i a", $c_time);
$t = Carbon::createFromFormat("H:i a", $t_time);
$minutes = $c->diffInMinutes($t); // returns 256 minutes, you can use either Carbon or pure DateTime objects to convert this
```

Comment: Actually, as long as you're using Composer in your project, you can use Carbon : )

Comment: Correct, my point was that Carbon is a dependency of Laravel so you have it anyway :)